# How redirect all traffic in Windows over vidalia tor?

Tags: tcp, udp, traffic, tor

How to redirect all traffic in Windows over vidalia tor?
I try use Proxifier but it seems to redirect only selected application? but i need to redirect all outgoing traffic
example:

```
redirect all traffic from cmd.exe ping www.host.com; 
redirect all traffic from cmd.exe d:\python\python.exe inet.py -url "www.host.com"
```

and packet throught TOR.

Comment: CMD, PING, and PHYTON are separate programs. You'll have to specify them directly and not via CMD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I think you are suggesting is called a transparent tor proxy.  I do not think it is recommend to run a transparent tor proxy on Windows (because of DNS leaks and other security issues).

One solution, and I think the easiest solution, is to setup a transparent tor proxy on a router/switch running [OpenWRT](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/Torouter/OpenWRT_setup_notes).  If you do this on a second router (which is optional), you could then use that second router when ever you needed tor.

Another solution is to use a virtual machine running Linux.  I would recommend using virtualbox.  You can then create a linux machine on virtualbox.  Once the virtual machine is up you can set it up to be a [transparent tor proxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy).

If you are not comfortable with Linux, you can use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) in a virtual machine.  Tails is a Linux live DVD or live USB that does everything through tor and can be run on a virtual machine.

Lastly, if you want to be creative,  you might be able to setup a virtual machine, or a second server, running Linux and a VPN server that is setup to be a transparent tor proxy.  This might require two virtual network cards (instead the 1 by default).  Then all you would need to do is VPN into the Linux machine from the windows machine and all your traffic would go through Tor (:

Answer (score 2):

You can only redirect TCP traffic. TOR does not support UDP traffic (some filesharing and games) and ICMP traffic (PING). For TCP traffic, Cantormath gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tallow seems to be a good Windows solution: https://reqrypt.org/tallow.html